# XSD: Either/Or syntax

Tags: xml, xsd, switch-statement

How can i do either/or validation in an XSD? e.g. in the following xml fragment, if the `action` is `A` (*add*), then subsequent attributes and elements are `required`:

```
<Post postID="22793" action="A" ...>
   <Transaction ...>
      <Disposition ...>
         <AccountInformation ... />
         <ThirdPartyInformation ... />
      </Disposition>
      <IndividualInformation ... />
   </Transaction>

   ...
</Post>
```

but if the **action** is **D** then subsequent attributes, and attributes, are forbidden::

```
<Post postID="22793" action="D" />
```

That is: if the *action* is *delete* (`D`), then the remaining attributes change from

- required

to

- prohibited

and the subsequent elements switch from

```
minOccurences="1" maxOccurrences="unbounded"
```

to

```
minOccurrences="0" maxOccurrences="0"
```

Is it possible to use XSD to define xml structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of [the big criticisms of XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)#Criticism) is its failure to

> ...provide no facilities to state that the value or presence of one attribute is dependent on the values or presence of other attributes (so-called co-occurrence constraints).

So it cannot specify constraints like the one you describe. In most circumstances, I've seen projects use XSLT to validate their documents where XSD fails. However [other Schema languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_Language_Comparison) do exist, and you may have more success with them. I've heard of some people switching to [Relax NG](http://www.relaxng.org/) for various reasons.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Providing a link to others having the same issue shows that a)what i'm doing is not uncommon b)others want to do it c)it isn't possible. And it's **c** that is the accepted answer: not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In XSD version 1.1 now it is possible.

[XSD 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#intro1.1)

> The Working Group's strategic guidelines for changes between versions
> 1.0 and 1.1 can be summarized as follows:
>
> 2.Support for co-occurrence constraints (which will certainly involve additions to the XML transfer syntax, which will not be understood by
> 1.0 processors)

Of course, XPATH 2.0 is being used for assertions on simple and complex types. A new tag is defined for this purpose.

*xs:assert*

Another useful new mechanism is

> Type Alternative components provide associations between boolean
> conditions (as XPath expressions) and Type Definitions. They are used
> in conditional type assignment.

*xs:alternative*

```
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:anyType">
  <xs:alternative test="@type='text'" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@type='html'" type="htmlContentType"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@type='xhtml'" type="xhtmlContentType"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@type" type="xs:error"/>
  <xs:alternative type="xs:string"/>
</xs:element>
```

You can read more in [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/)